# How can I create a quarter-hourly output in Oracle SQL using the connect by function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with the connect by function in Oracle SQL. I have follwing data:

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14.07.2022 10:30:00 | 14.07.2022 11:45:00 | N |

START- & END_DATE are always quarter-hourly.
I need a sql query with an output like this.

| QUARTER_HOUR* | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 14.07.2022 10:45:00 | N |
| 14.07.2022 11:00:00 | N |
| 14.07.2022 11:15:00 | N |
| 14.07.2022 11:30:00 | N |
| 14.07.2022 11:45:00 | N |

*Endtime of the quarter hour

I tried this, but unfortunately this won't work:

```
WITH interval_data AS (
  SELECT
    START_DATE + ((LEVEL - 1) / 96) AS quarter_hour,
    VALUE
  FROM
    table
  CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= ((END_DATE - START_DATE) *96) + 1
)
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(quarter_hour, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS quarter_hour,
  VALUE
FROM
  interval_data
ORDER BY
  quarter_hour;
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/khmyJBzR), don't subtract 1 from level and remove 1 in connect by clause.

Comment: It is more readable when you use `interval` syntax: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iVudzORt).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive subquery for this:

```
create table t (id, start_date, end_date, value) AS 
(SELECT 1, TO_DATE('14.07.2022 10:30:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('14.07.2022 11:45:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, TO_DATE('15.07.2022 10:30:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),TO_DATE('15.07.2022 11:00:00','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'Y' FROM DUAL
);



WITH t_qtr (id, qtr_start_date, end_date, VALUE) AS
(
  select id, 
         start_date,
         end_date,
         value
    from t
  UNION ALL
  select id, 
         qtr_start_date + interval '15' minute,
         end_date,
         value
    from t_qtr
   where qtr_start_date < end_date
  
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY qtr_start_date SET t_order
SELECT id,
       TO_CHAR(qtr_start_date,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as QUARTER_HOUR,
       value
FROM   t_qtr;

        ID QUARTER_HOUR        V
---------- ------------------- -
         1 14.07.2022 10:30:00 N
         1 14.07.2022 10:45:00 N
         1 14.07.2022 11:00:00 N
         1 14.07.2022 11:15:00 N
         1 14.07.2022 11:30:00 N
         1 14.07.2022 11:45:00 N
         2 15.07.2022 10:30:00 Y
         2 15.07.2022 10:45:00 Y
         2 15.07.2022 11:00:00 Y
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran the below and it looks OK to me:

```
WITH tb as (
  select date '2023-01-31' start_date
   ,date '2023-02-04' end_date
 from dual    
) 
,interval_data AS (
  SELECT
  START_DATE + ((LEVEL - 1) / 96) AS quarter_hour,
  start_date,
  end_date
FROM tb
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ((END_DATE - START_DATE) *96) + 1
```

)

```
   SELECT
     TO_CHAR(quarter_hour, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS quarter_hour,
         start_date,
         end_date
   FROM interval_data
   ORDER BY quarter_hour
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your replies.
This is really confusing to me. It works when I put my_table in another WITH Subquery clause.

Here I get a result immediately.

```
WITH tb as (
  select start_date, end_date, value 
 from my_table where ID = 1    
) 
,interval_data AS (
  SELECT
  START_DATE + ((LEVEL) / 96) AS quarter_hour,
  VALUE
FROM tb
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ((END_DATE - START_DATE) *96)
)

   SELECT
     TO_CHAR(quarter_hour, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS quarter_hour,
         VALUE
   FROM interval_data
   ORDER BY quarter_hour
;
```

But when I just use one or no WITH Clause then nothing happens within a 30 minute period:

```
WITH interval_data AS (
  SELECT
    START_DATE + ((LEVEL) / 96) AS quarter_hour,
    VALUE
  FROM
    my_table where ID = 1
  CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= ((END_DATE - START_DATE) *96) 
)
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(quarter_hour, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS quarter_hour,
  VALUE
FROM
  interval_data
ORDER BY
  quarter_hour;
```